# ruby like query error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-like

This is my code for mysql like query:

```
def search
    params.permit!
    @query = params[:query]
    respond_to do |format|
        @outlet = Outlet.select(:name).where("name like ?","%#{@query}%")
        format.json { render json: @outlet }
    end
end
```

It renders all of my data from table. It does not respond to the query. Do you have any ideas?

My route is:

```
 namespace :api do
  resources :outlets, :defaults => { :format => 'json'}
  get 'outlets/auto_complete' => 'outlets#auto_complete', :defaults =>       { :format => 'json'}
  post 'outlets/search' => 'outlets#search', :defaults => { :format => 'json' }

 end
```

The development.log is

```
    Started POST "/api/outlets/search" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-05-30 16:56:22 +0530
Processing by Api::OutletsController#search as JSON
  Parameters: {"outlet"=>{"query"=>"life"}}
  [1m[35mOutlet Load (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT `outlets`.`name` FROM `outlets`  WHERE (name like '%%')
Completed 200 OK in 28ms (Views: 22.3ms | ActiveRecord: 1.7ms)
```

Comment: it render all of my data form the table,.. the query is not working

Comment: show what data you are passing via `params[:query]`,,, show the console log..

Comment: i'm using postmen rest client,.. the params i'm passing is outlets[:query] value is 'something'

Comment: probably the value you are passing matched all records.. that's why. But I am sure query is working.

Comment: no,.. the value i'm passing  is very particular in one data

Comment: Well.. try in your rails console....

Comment: i tried with raw data,.. it showing the correct answer,.. while having the query it showing all the data

Comment: raw data mean? raw `SQL`?

Comment: i removed the #{@query} and i put some string variable there,.. and it worked fine

Comment: It means `params[:query]` is either `""` or `nil`. Show me the rails development log data while you are hitting the `#search` action..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the *log* file and below trace :-

```
Parameters: {"outlet"=>{"query"=>"life"}}
```

I found the issue. You need to do `@query = params[:outlet][:query]`.

Answer (score 1):

It is because params[:query] is nil, so the resulting sql is

```
where name like '%%'
```

You do have a query parameter in params[:outlet][:query] which you could use without changing your view.

However, as you're not creating or updating an Outlet, and query probably isn't an attribute of the Outlet model, it doesn't really make sense to structure the form in this way.

Try using form_tag instead of form_for and don't pass it an instance of Outlet. Also use text_field_tag instead of form.text_field. This way params[:query] will be set, instead of being wrapped under params[:outlet].

The new form would look a bit like this:

```
<%= form_tag do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :query %>
  <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```